# Why can't I position my image and search bar on the right side of the nav bar?

Tags: css

Inside my nav bar I had a search field positioned exactly where I wanted in the right corner using float: right;

The problem is that I tried to add a profile picture to the left of the search bar (also using float:right), but not only did that not position the profile picture in the upper right corner, but it also knocked my search bar visually outside of the nav bar (below it).

I'm guessing I can't use float: right; for both of these elements, so my question is how what can I do with div nav (profile pic is nested inside) and div head-search (search bar) in order to position both of these in the top right corner?

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/hlEjs

```
  nav {
  float: right;
  width:13em;
  margin:10px auto;
  background:#f6f6f6;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.user-avatar img{
        border-radius: 50px;
        float:right;
        margin-left:200px;
        margin-top:1px;
        width: 30px;
        height: auto;
}

#head-search        {float:right; width:350px;}
#head-search span   {float:right; color: #008000; font:normal 12px/46px 'Strait',sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you, you want your nav and search bar to be aligned right?  Simply create a container div and float the container.

```
div id="navsb-container">
div id="nav"></div>
div id="sb"></div>
</div>


#navsb-container{
clear:both;
float:right;
width:80%;
display:block;
}

#nav{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width:39%;
}

#sb{
float:right;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width:49%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search bar is pushed out because the width of the container is not wide enough to contain it.

Let's break this down to a simple example.

Here is a simple (broken) layout. "Run code snippet" to see the results:

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
nav,
.search {
  height: 100px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #F00;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" />
  <nav>Nav</nav>
  <div class="search">Search</div>
</header>
```

**2 problems with this example:**

1. The search should be on the far right, but here is shown before the nav
2. When the header gets to small, the search breaks its layout and is displayed underneath the nav

**The simplest solution:**

1. Switch the order of the search and nav in your HTML to get the correct position
2. Place a `min-width` on the header to prevent it from getting too small

In your Codepen example you have `@media`. Use this to control what happens when the viewport goes past its  `min-width`.

Looks better:

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
  min-width: 600px;
}
nav,
.search {
  height: 100px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #F00;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" />
  <div class="search">Search</div>
  <nav>Nav</nav>
</header>
```